# Bootstrap Confirmation Dialog in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

How to create a delete confirmation dialog? If 'yes' clicks delete the message, if 'no' clicks cancel delete operation.

[image: Popup dialog]

Currently I have like this in my view:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-large btn-info msgbox-confirm">Confirm Message</a>
```

And how to change the dialog box content?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Are you asking how to develop  the process or accepting/rejecting with JS/Jquery, or with PHP using page reloading, or in general? And what behaviour do you mean with "changing the dialog box content"? Button disappering after clicking?

Comment: Robert, Am Just asking, if yes clicked means i need to call one method in controller, and if no or cancel clicked means it should not do anything.

Comment: This code for Confirmation Dialog in PHP solves my problem. '<br/><br/>'
`<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" class="btn btn-large btn-info msgbox-confirm"onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete the Code?');">Delete</a>`

Comment: What's the difference between no and cancel? Just asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do a confirm or bootstrap confirm in PHP as PHP is server side code.

What you will be after is how to use Javascript to create a confirm box.

**Plain Javascript**

Using plain standard javascript this would only need a button with a function

*HTML*

```
<button onclick="show_confirm()">Click me</button>
```

*javascript*

```
// function : show_confirm()
function show_confirm(){
    // build the confirm box
    var c=confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete?");

    // if true
    if (c){
        alert("true");
     }else{ // if false
        alert("false");
    }
  }
```

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3listone/zXDJv/)

**Bootstrap with jQuery**

This way is a little more complex as you are adding in 3rd-party libraries.

To start off with you will need to create a modal to act as your confirm box.

*HTML*

```
<div id="confirmModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Delete?</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Are you sure you wish to delete?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <button onclick="ok_hit()" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Same button as before with a little bit of styling

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="show_confirm()">Click me</button>
```

and then the

*Javascript*

```
// function : show_confirm()
function show_confirm(){
    // shows the modal on button press
    $('#confirmModal').modal('show');
}

// function : ok_hit()
function ok_hit(){
    // hides the modal
    $('#confirmModal').modal('hide');
    alert("OK Pressed");

    // all of the functions to do with the ok button being pressed would go in here
}
```

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3listone/zgzXM/1/)

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach with javascript:

```
<a onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure that you want to permanently delete the selected element?'))return false" class="btn btn-large btn-info msgbox-confirm" href="?action=delete">Delete</a>
```

This way, when user clicks on "Delete", a dialog will ask her/him to confirm. If it is accepted, the page is reloaded with a parameter in the url (change to whatever you need). Otherwise, the dialog is closed and nothing happens.

Comment: Rober, I need the Confirm dialog style as the above image, but the above answer solve half of the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
function deletechecked()
{ 
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure that you want to permenantly delete the selected element?")
    if (answer){
        document.messages.submit();
    }

    return false;  
}
</script> 

<a href="<?php echo base_url('department/deletedept/'.$row['dept_id']);?>" onclick="return deletechecked();" title="Delete" data-rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-danger">
```